# Using .slugignore with Heroku and S3 isn't working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, amazon-s3

### Background

I've a repo that's too big for Heroku, about 500mb. This is due to a lot of images in the `app/assets/images` folder. I recently tried syncing my images to S3 instead of storing them in my repo.

I used the gem `asset_sync` to sync the files and `.slugignore` file to force Heroku to ignore the assets files, so now the repo is to about 70mb, but there's still a problem. Now the files aren't in the repo at Heroku, which means that `image_path` can't find the file and is therefore linking `image_path "image.png"` to `/images/image.png` instead of `/assets/image.png`, a file that doesn't exist in S3.

How can one solve this?

### To summarize

Removing all assets from Heroku using `.slugignore` and pointing all images to S3 results in `image_path "f.png"` linking to `http://s3.com/images/f.png` instead of `http://s3.com/assets/f.png`.

Note that using the absolute path works. `image_path "/assets/f.png"`, but then rails isn't adding the digest after the file.

### Decencies

- rails `4.0.11`
- asset_sync `1.1.0`

### Files

- `.slugignore` https://gist.github.com/oleander/2699ce91be6cfbf8b90a
- `config/environments/production.rb` https://gist.github.com/oleander/39e1ddeb60e5f697e6b1

### Update

I'm currently using this quick fix to force rails to use absolute path to my images.

```
# app/helpers/application_helper.rb
module ApplicationHelper

  def image_tag(path, *args)
    if path[0] != "/" and path !~ /^http/
      path = File.join("/assets", path)
    end

    super(path, *args)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not related to you ignoring the assets folder on heroku. The problem is that asset_sync by default maps to the root of your bucket, However your assets is under the asset subfolder in your bucket.   To fix that add an asset prefix in your production.rb.

```
config.assets.prefix = "/assets"
```